# Object oriented programming same methods

Tags: oop

can i have same method name with same params and params type in a single class? how about in a different class with same name?

In response to the first part is the ans overriding? what about the second part  of the questions "how about in a different class with same name?"

Comment: What language are we talking about? How about you ask a compiler aka simply try it yourself?

Comment: I am talking about java

Comment: This will be simpler if you try it yourself and if you have error while doing it. feel free to post your class and your output error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there a few examples in which the answer to both your questions is yes, but as far as my knowledge in Java and Objective C is concerned, you cannot have two methods named exactly the same with same parameter names and types in the same class. I believe that you can in two different classes, but you generally shouldn't, just to keep your code simple and easily understandable, but you can do it all the same.

Comment: Not at all a problem. Happy Coding! :D